# userID from phpMyAdmin not printed in Apache logs

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I've configured my phpMyAdmin website with the following lines in the apache config:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{userID}n %{userStatus}n" pma_combined
ErrorLog     /srv/wwwroot/phpMyAdmin/logs/errors.log
CustomLog    /srv/wwwroot/phpMyAdmin/logs/access.log pma_combined
```

But my apache logs never show the *userID* nor *userStatus*:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [...] "GET /index.php?token=... HTTP/1.1" 200 5200 "https://example.com/index.php?token=..." "Mozilla/(...)" - -
```

My phpMyAdmin config contains:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']        = 'cookie';
```

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a few days when I found a fix.
My solution was to run PhpMyAdmin as "Apache mod_php" instead of "FCGId"